# Fuel module disable create button

Tags: codeigniter, fuelcms

It's posible to disable the button "Create" in Fuel CMS custome modules.

I' know that I can config the name with create_action_name but I want to disable the button or hide it.

Answer (score 1):

```
'item_actions' => array('view')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['modules']['dummy'] = array(
'table_actions'=>array('edit','view','delete'),
'item_actions' => array('edit','save','view','delete')
);
```

Comment: It will just remove Create button from Top bar in fuel cms

Comment: You have to Add this code to My_fuel_modules.php in fuel_cms/applications/config folder

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your explanations into your answer, and delete the comments afterwards. Thanks.